# Read Same Text File in Different Methods

Tags: c#, winforms, text-files, readfile

In the `BtnNext_Click` method it's just reading from the text file like it was a different text file, and not from the one that already was opened.  It does not go from line to line. 
I need help

Here is the code:

```
public void ScrubData()
{           
    string FileName1;
    string FilePath1;

    // Display an OpenFile Dialog box for user
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt Files|*.txt";
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a txt File";

    // Show the Dialog. If user clicked OK in the dialog
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            String strFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            String strFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName);
            String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFileName);
            String strFileNameAndPathNew = strFilePath +
                openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + "\\" + fileName + "_scrubbed.txt";

            // If scrubbed file exists, delete it first
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(strFileNameAndPathNew))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(strFileNameAndPathNew);
            } // End IF
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName))
            {
                int lineCount = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(strFileName).Length;
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(strFileName);
                // Status label 
                LblStatus.Text = "File Loaded Successfully";
                LblStatus.Visible = true;
                string line;
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    const char DELIM = '|';
                    // MessageBox.Show(line);

                    string[] word = line.Split(DELIM);
                     Txt2NormAccNum.Text = word[3];
                    //string accScrubbed = ReplaceData(word[0],"SSN");
                    Txt3NormAmnt.Text = word[4];
                    Txt4NormFirstNam.Text = word[1];
                    Txt5NormLastNam.Text = word[2];
                    Txt6NormSS.Text = word[0];
                    Txt7NormItem.Text = word[5];
                } // End WHILE
            } // End IF
            else
            {
                // Status label 
                LblStatus.Text = "File Load Failed!";
                LblStatus.Visible = true;
            } // End ELSE
            // Text box one code:
            FileName1 = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            Txt1.Text = FileName1;
            //
        } // End TRY
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
             if (e1.Source != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IOException source: {0}", e1.Source);
                throw;
            } // End IF
        } // End CATCH
    } // End IF
} // End Scrub Method
```

I need to reuse the variables such as "strFileName" in my next method.

I am creating a previous & next buttons to cycle through each line in the text file:

```
public void BtnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader myReader2 = new StreamReader("colin.txt");
    string line2 = "";

    while (line2 != null)
    {
        line2 = myReader2.ReadLine();
        if (line2 != null)
        {
            const char DELIM = '|';
            // MessageBox.Show(line);
            string[] word = line2.Split(DELIM);
            Txt2NormAccNum.Text = word[3];
            Txt3NormAmnt.Text = word[4];
            Txt4NormFirstNam.Text = word[1];
            Txt5NormLastNam.Text = word[2];
            Txt6NormSS.Text = word[0];
            Txt7NormItem.Text = word[5];

            //Txt12ScrubSS.Text;
            //Txt10ScrubFirstNam.Text;
            //Txt11ScrubLastNam.Text;
            //Txt8ScrubAcctNum.Text;
            //Txt9ScrubAmt.Text;
            //Txt13ScrubItem.Text;
        }
    }
    myReader2.Close();

} // end method
```

If you see what Im saying: The design is:  User opens file, first line of text from file is displayed on form, Then I have a 'previous" and 'next' button that I want to cycle through the lines of text from that same file.

@Tim Yeah I think I know what your saying Here look at this:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;

    namespace Project2_DataScrubber
    {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{ // Begin Class #1

    public Form1()
    { // Begin Main Method


        InitializeComponent();

        // MessageBox.Show(GetRandomNumbers().ToString());


    } // End Main Method

    private void Btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { // Btn4 CLICK Method

        // Closes Form 1
        this.Close();
    } // End Method

    private void Btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { // Btn3 CLICK Method

        // Display alert message box of are you sure you want to reset the data
        DialogResult dialogResult1 = MessageBox.Show("Are you want to reset the data?", "ALERT", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult1 == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            // Resets all the data, textboxes, ect
            Txt1.Text = "No file loaded.";
            Txt2NormAccNum.Clear();
            Txt3NormAmnt.Clear();
            Txt4NormFirstNam.Clear();
            Txt5NormLastNam.Clear();
            Txt6NormSS.Clear();
            Txt7NormItem.Clear();
            Txt8ScrubAcctNum.Clear();
            Txt9ScrubAmt.Clear();
            Txt10ScrubFirstNam.Clear();
            Txt11ScrubLastNam.Clear();
            Txt12ScrubSS.Clear();
            Txt13ScrubItem.Clear();
            Txt14ScrubYesNo.Clear();
            LblStatus.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (dialogResult1 == DialogResult.No)
        {
            // Do nothing
        }

    } // End Method

    public  void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { // Btn1 CLICK Method

        ScrubData();
    } // End Method

    public void Btn2_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Txt2NormAccNum.Text != "" || Txt3NormAmnt.Text != "" || Txt4NormFirstNam.Text != "" || Txt5NormLastNam.Text != "" ||
            Txt6NormSS.Text != "" || Txt7NormItem.Text != "")
        {
                                                                //
            Txt12ScrubSS.Text = GetRandomNumbers().ToString();  // Replace SS textbox
            //
            #region
            int lastNameLetters = Txt5NormLastNam.Text.Length;  //   
            string lettersTwo = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            Random randLetters = new Random();
            string randomString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < lastNameLetters; i++)
            {                                                   // Replace Last Name
                randomString += lettersTwo
                    [randLetters.Next(0, 25)].ToString();
            }
            Txt11ScrubLastNam.Text = randomString;              //
            #endregion
            #region
            var newAccountNum = "";                             //
            int numOfCharacters = 4; // # to leave behind
            for (var i = 0; i<Txt2NormAccNum.Text.Length - numOfCharacters; i++)
            {
                newAccountNum += "X";                           // Replace Account Number
            }
            newAccountNum += Txt2NormAccNum.Text.Substring
                (Txt2NormAccNum.Text.Length - numOfCharacters);
            Txt8ScrubAcctNum.Text = newAccountNum;              //
            #endregion
            #region
            double moneyAmountDoub = 0;                         //
            string moneyAmountStr = "";
            moneyAmountStr = Txt3NormAmnt.Text;
            moneyAmountDoub = Convert.ToDouble(moneyAmountStr);
            if (moneyAmountDoub > 100.00)
            {                                                   // Get Yes or No answer
                Txt14ScrubYesNo.Text = "Yes";               
            }
            else
            {
                Txt14ScrubYesNo.Text = "No";
            }                                                   //
            #endregion

            Txt10ScrubFirstNam.Text = Txt4NormFirstNam.Text;
            Txt13ScrubItem.Text = Txt7NormItem.Text;
            Txt13ScrubItem.Text = Txt7NormItem.Text;
            Txt9ScrubAmt.Text = Txt3NormAmnt.Text;




        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Information missing from the Data section");
        }
    }

    public void ScrubData()
    { // Begin Scrub Method
```

Comment: I can't really see what the problem is, but the whole `Start XXX`/`End XXX` really detracts from your code readability.

Comment: Based on what you've posted it's hard to tell what (if any) problem you're having.  What is the expected behavior vs what's happening?  What do you mean it looks like it's reading like it's a different file?  You'd need to use class fields (or properties) to store the file path so you can reuse it in different methods.

Comment: I want to have a dynamic file name not just one that is static like "bob.txt"

Comment: I want to use the openfiledialog let the user choose the file then store that file info like the file name in a global variable so i call it later

Comment: @Colin - so why not store in a class level (global) variable then?  Do note though, that when you create a `StreamReader`, it will be positioned at the start of the file - which means you will only get the first line everytime.  Better approach would be to create the `StreamReader` at a higher scope level - but then you have to be careful to manage it's state.

Comment: @Tim So put the the 'openfiledialog'  code in a class too with the rest of file info? and then call it, would that work and still allow the user to choose a different file?

Comment: @Colin - the code you already have is in a class, right?  You don't need to create a new class - simply make the variables you intend to use across methods class level variables.  I.e., `public class MyClass { private string fileName; private string filePath; public void SomeMethod() { } public void SomeMethod2() { } }`.  Both `fileName` and `filePath` will be available to any methods defined in the class `MyClass`.

Comment: @Tim No its a method sadly

Comment: @Tim Should I convert it to a class perhaps?

Comment: @Colin - that doesn't make sense.  You have methods outside of a class?  Can you post the beginning and end of the file that has the methods?  you don't need to post all the code.

Comment: @Tim What do you mean? Should I just post the entire code?

Comment: @Colin - the file that contains the method(s) you posted - is the only thing in that file the method code?  I would expect it to be in a class like `public class Form1 : Form { }` or something similiar.  Otherwise, how would you call those methods?  They can't exist outside of a class or some other object.

Comment: @Tim okay I edited it for you take a look

Comment: @Colin - writing an answer.  Stand by.

Comment: @Tim Okay! standing by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to do.  First, you need to create class level variables (more properly referred to as fields) to hold information that needs to be accessed by different methods.

Secondly, you need to keep track of where you are (what line) in the file, because everytime you create a `StreamReader`, it will position the reader at the first line.  As a corollary, as RogueBukkitDev said, you should read the file one time and dump it into a `List<string>` or an array (`string[]`).  You would then increase or decrease the current position in the collection based on the user's direction - forward or back.

It could look something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 

    // Class level fields
    private string fileName = String.Empty;
    private string[] fileLines;
    private int currentLine = 0;
    const char DELIM = '|';

    public void ScrubData()
    {           

        // Display an OpenFile Dialog box for user
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt Files|*.txt";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a txt File";

        // Show the Dialog. If user clicked OK in the dialog
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                newFileName = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}_scrubed.txt",
                           openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory,
                           Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));
                fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
                currentLine = 0;
            } 
        }
    }

    public void BtnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (currentLine <= fileLines.Length)
        {
            string line2 = fileLines[currentLine];
            string[] word = line2.Split(DELIM);

            Txt2NormAccNum.Text = word[3];
            Txt3NormAmnt.Text = word[4];
            Txt4NormFirstNam.Text = word[1];
            Txt5NormLastNam.Text = word[2];
            Txt6NormSS.Text = word[0];
            Txt7NormItem.Text = word[5];

            currentLine = currentLine + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Lots of changes here, and I ommitted code that wasn't relevant to the example.

First, I declare 4 fields - one for the fileName, one for the scrubbed filename, one for the current line of the file, and one constant for the delimiter.

Next, in the `ScrubData` method were the file is selected by the user, it simply calls `File.ReadAllLines()`, which will return an array of strings (one array element per line), and stores it in the class level field `fileLines`.  It also sets the `currentLine` to 0, in case the user is choosing a different file before exiting the program.

In the `btnNext_Click` event handler, it reads the current line from the array of lines (`fileLines`) - after making sure you won't have an index out bounds error, then splits them on the delimiter and populates the text boxes.  It then increases the `currentLine` by one.

To go back, it would be essentially the same logic, except that you would **decrease** `currentLine` by 1 (and check to make sure you don't go past 0).

This is the basic outline of what we've been trying to explain.  You may need to modify it to suit your actual needs, but the principle remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it doesn't go from line to line. Each time the button is clicked you are simply reading the first line.

The best approach is to read all the lines in the file into a `List<string>` and have an `int counter` which you increment or decrement depending on if they move back or forward. Just increment/decrement each time and set the text to `yourListVar[counter]`

Or, if you want it to read from the file each time you can cycle through `ReadLine()`'s until you hit the index that matches the counter.

Comment: Okay cool thanks, but if you notice my streamreader is reading from a "static" filename that coded in there. I want it to read from a dynamic file name like the one where the user opened and chose like in the first block of code i have

Comment: @Colin Update the List and set the counter to 0 each time they open a new file perhaps? Have a function which populates that list for the sake of abstraction, ideally.

Comment: Yeah that could work, But like I want this counter to go through the current file that was opened in the first block of code. If you see what Im saying: The design is:  User opens file, first line of text from file is displayed on form, Then I have a 'previous" and 'next' button that I want to cycle through the lines of text from that same file.

Comment: @Colin Then I don't see what's wrong? When do you want to "change files"? It seems you want all the lines to be from the first file they opened.

Comment: Yeah I dont want to change files. And yes I do want all the lines to be from the first file they opened. The problem is I cant access the variables such as "FileName", "FilePath", ect from the first block of code, in my next block of code. So Im stuck as to how to access the that same text file (Since the user could pick any), from a different method in my code. This is hard to explain haha

Comment: One simple solution would be to make the filename a class level variable.

Comment: @Tim Yes, but the user gets to choose any text file from when the openfiledialog is clicked and thus a dynamic file name so I cant do a class

Comment: @Colin - yes, you can.   The code you posted is in a `class`, correct?  Simply set the filename as a class level variable in that class, and then set the value base don the user's input from the `OpenFileDialog`.

Comment: @Tim Well actually the code I posted is in a method.? So would your way still work?

Comment: @Colin Unless you mark the class-scope variable `const` you can easily change it at any time. Declare the var outside of the method, then initialise it inside the method. It will be the same class-wide. I'd recommend not storing the `StreamReader` but rather the `List<string>` I talked about.